# Caching index.php page's search engine having siteController but no model in yii PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, caching, yii

I'm a newbie to yii..
To cache search engine in **index.php** page I've added

```
'cache' => array(
      'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
),
```

In my **main.php** page.
In the **siteController.php** I've added

```
if(isset($_POST['location']))                
    {
        $val = explode(',',$_POST['location']);
        //print_r($val);
        foreach($val as $val2)
        {
        $val1 = "INSERT INTO cache_search(property_id,property_name,keyword) SELECT a.id,a.title,$val from property AS a
        WHERE a.description like '%'.$val.'%' OR a.city like '%'.$val.'%' OR a.address like '%'.$val.'%' OR a.zip like '%'.$val.'%' OR a.country like '%'.$val.'%' OR";     
        $value = "SELECT * FROM cache_search where keyword like '%'.$val.'%'";
        $command = YII::app()->db->createCommand($value);
        $command2 = YII::app()->db->createCommand($val1);
        if($cache = Yii::app()->cache !== null) 
        {
        $key  = md5(rand(10,10000));
        $result = $command->queryAll();
        Yii::app()->cache->set($key,$result,0);
    }
    else{

        $key = md5(rand(10,10000));
        $result = $command2->queryAll();
        Yii::app()->cache->get($key);
    }}}
```

Where *'location'* is the *name* for the **Search Engine** in **index.php** i.e in the *view* page.

Something like this:-

```
<div class="search-line">

                                <form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/map'); ?>" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group locality">
                                        <i class="fo">&#xe801;</i>
                                        <input name="location" class="form-control locality-txt" type="text" placeholder="Search by Locality, City, Project or Developer"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group type-sel">
                                        <div class="sel-holder">

                                            <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('type', '', $categoriesList,
                                                                           [
                                                                               'empty'=>'Any Property Type',
                                                                               'class'=>'type-sel',
                                                                           ]); ?>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('mode', 'index'); ?>
                                    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Search" id='prop_search'/>
                                </form>

                            </div>
```

I don't have any model for index page.
I want the application to hit the Database on the first search of new keywords in the search engine and store in **cache_search** table along with the matched keys in the *description* in the **property** table. And store searched keywords in the cache with unique keys for each keyword along with the **property name** from *title* column and **property id** from the *id* column from **property** table.
**Somehow like *Google* search engine does,provides results on every next searched keywords from cache in a drop down**

Basically I would like to use **CFileCache** or **CMemCache** but if there is any good caching options/codes please share with me.

Any Help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have random cache key for what?
2. Yii cache use md5 function for long keys.

Your code should be like:

```
cacheKey = genCacheKeyByPostData()
data = getFromCacheByKey (cacheKey)
if empty data then 
    data = getFromDbOSomethingElse
    saveDataToCache (key, data, expireTime)
end

use data
```

Comment: 1) "**genCacheKeyByPostData(),getFromCacheByKey()**"  Are these function built in yii,or I've to code these functions?  

2) Random Cache key to store data with unique ID.. Is there any function to get small keys?

3) I want the cached data to come as **drop-down** in the view if anyone enters the matching characters or numbers or special characters.. But it's not coming.

4) With my code the whole page is getting cached in the cache folder,but not the keywords..

How to get rid of these issues?

Comment: 1) pseudo code; 2) when you save data to cache you should know how get it. If your key is random you cannt be sure what kind of data strored. For example Yii::app()->cache->set(rand(0, 99999), 'Test data'); How retrieve 'Test data' from cache?

Comment: 1) Can't we retrieve data according to the searched keywords, Like it'll return data with id from cache? Alike we do with MySQL **like** ? I'm not that good at yii so it's bit tough to understand even from the yii forum documentation. 

2) So, we have to create a function and call it to get _ cacheKey_ right? 

3) How will it hit the database and store the data on the first hit and retrieve searched data from cache on next use?

Please share with me in detail or through blog written by you.. I'm so stuck